# Will Magento recognize a theme with empty folders?

Tags: magento-1, theme, frontend, design

I'm trying to learn Magento theme structure, I've been told that I should create a package and a theme folders under app/design/frontend and also under the skin directory, but **whenever I save the configuration , I get package with this name does not exist and cannot be set.**

[image: folder structure]

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is definitely the right thing to do.

To me, it sounds like a permission issue.

Check the permissions on the `base/default` folder in both `app` and `skin` and apply the same permissions recursively on your `tutsplus` folder, that should fix your issue.